# Как можно исправить проблему c плохим качеством картинок ocStore ( OpenCart ) в товаре?

Tags: php, opencart, img, изображения, ocstore

Вот сам сайт с примером http://texna.by/sadovaya-tekhnika/trimmery/patriot-pt-480
Проблема есть абсолюта на всех товарах. При первой загрузки уже самой карточки товара, первая картинка отображается в плохом качестве, но уже если навести на миниатюру ниже, то картинка становится нормальной. В чем может быть проблема ?

Есть еще один нюанс. Картинка в плохом качестве, у нее в имени есть _header
/img_425475_header-450x450_0.jpg

,а вот с хорошим качеством, уже после наведения на миниатюру, тот же самый путь, но с img_425475_big-450x450_0.jpg

Comment: Покажите код вывода картинок на карточке товара

Comment: @Dimus Какой модуль галереи карты товара (или что-то подобное) используете?

Answer (score -1):

`system/library/image.php`

```
public function save($file, $quality = 90)
```

поставьте `100` вместо `90`